# Is there a smart pointer type that requires multiple owners?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

A `std::shared_ptr` destroys the object it's managing when the reference count hits 0. However, I'm looking for a type of smart pointer where the object gets destroyed when the reference count drops below 2. Is there a smart pointer that will behave like this (or can I make a smart pointer behave like this, in a safe way)?

**Use case scenario**: I'm modelling a connection. The connection is owned (as in "ownership by a smart pointer") by the two end points it connects. As soon as one of the end points gets destroyed, the connection should be destroyed as well.

I know I could achieve this with classic `delete` statements in the appropriate destructors (since my requirement of "below 2" is super easy in this case). But I think this is a valid use case for a type of smart pointer, and I'm curious to see if I could do this using a modern way.

Comment: Seems to me like you just need some of your objects to hold `std::weak_ptr`

Comment: @StoryTeller write an answer :-)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the other endpoint tries to access it?

Comment: @Ven, I would but am not quite sure on how to fit it best onto the OP's scenario.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: The end point will always check if the connection is still there. So, ideally, the smart pointer on side B would automatically report a `nullptr` once the end point on side A gets destroyed.

Comment: I agree with @StoryTeller. If the object can be deleted while there are remaining co-owners of that object, then they need some way of checking if the object still exists. This is what you'd use a `weak_ptr` for.

Comment: ^ here you have your answer @StoryTeller :)

Comment: Mayby boost::intrusive_ptr can help ? It forces developer to define his own ref counting functions. 

Source: http://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.smartpointers-special-smart-pointers

Comment: @KerrekSB: that reminds me somewhat of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem. I'm curious - if suitably disclaimed - would you consider posting it anyway?

Comment: Will the refcount ever be greater than 2? I guess not, but it might be good to clarify this

Comment: @AaronMcDaid: In my particular case; no. But I guess someone could up with a scenario where the refcount is greater than X (X > 2), but once it drops below Y (Y > 0), there is no point in keeping the object.

Comment: @KerrekSB How do you do it so that if *either* remove the reference, the early destroy code is run, but if *both* do it, it is only run once?  How do you prevent both sides holding the same internal ref count when they have the same type?  In short, I ran into practical issues when I tried to sketch it out.

Comment: @Yakk: Hm, OK, maybe it's not simple at all :-S Damn that margin. You'd need to have two designated "weak observers" that you never alias from. So it wouldn't be "any last two", but "two specific last instances" that ended up dangling.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as a data structure.  What if the reference count drops to 1 and then goes back up to 2?  Memory management objects should make it so the object is deleted iff it's unreferencable, not delete the object then leave some reference around.  This feels very XY.

Comment: @Martijn Courteaux: What a Design Pattern is this? Do you have a three part connection: two connetion partners and one part, wich owns the connection? Please mark one of the post as the answer! And please make a conclusive statement about your unusual idea!

Answer (score 4):

Probably the easiest solution is for each side to have a `shared_ptr` to the object, a `weak_ptr` to the object, and a regular pointer to the other side's `shared_ptr`.

To access the object, you lock the `weak_ptr`. If it fails, the object is gone.

To destroy yourself, you lock the `weak_ptr`, reset the other side's `shared_ptr` through your regular pointer to it, reset your own `shared_ptr`, then get rid of the result of the lock on the `weak_ptr`.

Alternatively, you can just use a counter and a regular pointer. If the counter is 1, you know the other side is gone, so you can just destroy the object.

Comment: This seems like a complete overkill. This approach tries to use smart pointers, just to use smart pointers. (Or is it me?) If that is the only smart-pointer-solution that will come up, I'll stick with a couple of delete statements and pointer assignments in the destructors.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux, it's overkill because the ownership semantics you desire aren't that trivial. Both objects own the connection, but can also kill it irregardless of the other object being alive. It's a bit strange.

Comment: ... or write the pointer yourself. It is not that hard and this does not really sound that much.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for including what effect you're trying to achieve.

You don't want or need any special logic in the smart pointer. Both ends need an ordinary strong reference to the shared object. That cleanly expresses that it lives as long as either side knows about it.

What you do want instead is an event notification where either side can notify the other when it leaves. Then the surviving side can cleanly do the proper cleanup, including setting its (now last) shared_ptr to null, but also doing anything else that is logically required.

Answer (score 1):

As you have two owners, and when either dies you want to kill it, I might do something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct shared_connection {
  // by default, kill the connection if we are connected:
  ~shared_connection() {
    sever();
  }
  // wrap a shared pointer to the connection data:
  shared_connection( std::shared_ptr<T> p ):
    ptr(std::make_shared<std::shared_ptr<T>>(std::move(p)))
  {}
  // create a new connection:
  shared_connection fork() const {
    return {ptr};
  }
  // an even more explicit move:
  shared_connection transfer() {
    return std::move(*this);
  }
  friend void swap( shared_connection& lhs, shared_connection& rhs ) {
    std::swap( lhs.ptr, rhs.ptr );
  }
  // move only type:
  shared_connection(shared_connection&& src)
  {
    swap(*this, src);
  };
  shared_connection& operator=(shared_connection&& src)
  {
    auto tmp = std::move(src);
    swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
  };
  // lock it for use.  The connection can die
  // but the data will persist until the lock ends:
  std::shared_ptr<T> lock() const {
    if (!ptr) return {}; // don't break if we have been abandon()ed
    return atomic_load(ptr.get());
  }
  // do not kill the connection:
  void abandon() {
    ptr = {};
  }
  // kill the connection:
  void sever() {
    atomic_store(ptr.get(), std::shared_ptr<T>{});
    abandon();
  }
  // please just lock instead of calling this:
  explicit operator bool() const {
    return (bool)lock();
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::shared_ptr<T>> ptr;
};
template<class T, class...Args>
shared_connection<T> make_shared_connection( Args&&... args ) {
  return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

First, create a `shared_connection` via a `std::make_shared<T>`.

Then `.fork()` it to the other party.  When *any* of the `shared_connection`s go away, the internal `T` is destroyed *unless* one of the `shared_connection`s have it `.lock()`ed.

I think I got the atomic code right so it supports the two sides of the connection being in different threads.  It should also support multi-party connections.

The first shared pointer represents the shared control over the unlocked lifetime of the connection.  The second shared pointer represents the ability to persist the connection for the duration of a short operation.

`.abandon()` permits a someone to disconnect without killing the connection.  `.sever()` lets you destroy the shared connection data without destroying the object.

Code not tested.

If you want each side of the connection to share ownership within a bunch of code over their end of the shared connection, do a shared pointer to that shared connection.  Because nothing says loving like a shared pointer to a shared pointer to a shared pointer.

We could also avoid the possibility of the inner shared pointer "leaking" by blocking access to it within an applicator:

```
template<class F, class R=std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F(T const&)>>>
std::optional<R> read( F&& f ) const {
  auto p = lock();
  if (!p) return {};
  T const& t = *p;
  return std::make_optional<R>( std::forward<F>(f)(t) );
}
template<class F, class R=std::decay_t<std::result_of_t<F(T&)>>>
std::optional<R> write( F&& f ) const {
  auto p = lock();
  if (!p) return {};
  T& t = *p;
  return std::make_optional<R>( std::forward<F>(f)(t) );
}
```

by replacing the public `.lock()` with the above methods.

Comment: Once again, the fundamental theorem of software engineering comes to the rescue...

Comment: Not sure why we need the inner pointer to be `std::shared_ptr`. Why not `std::unique_ptr`?

Comment: @milleniumbug `lock` returns a copy of the inner pointer. Also `unique_ptr` doesn't have atomic operations.

Comment: @milleniumbug If you are working on the inner pointer, and the other connection terminates, your pointer stays alive until you dispose of your `.lock()`.  This is the only way to handle this concurrently: you must have a way to extend the lifetime of the resource that someone asynchronously has the right to destroy.  Even without multithreading, it is the only way to be sane.  That, and atomic.